Is there a way to set up Amazon SES Easy DKIM via an API?
I'm thinking of a use case where a SaaS provider is using Amazon SES to send email as their customer's domains. In order this properly, DKIM needs so be configured for that domain. One approach would be for the SaaS provider to log into the Amazon SES console, start the Easy DKIM configuration process, and provide the DNS records to the customer for the customer to add to their domain, and then the return to the SES console to verify the domain
Ideally, this process would be integrated into the SaaS so that it is transparent to the user. I've looked around the AWS APIs for an API to deploy Easy DKIM, and I can 't find anything, but I've never used any AWS APIs, so I could easily be overlooking something.
